# disable right click on datagrid while in edit mode

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, contextmenustrip, editmode

I have ContextMenuStrip that on right click shows something to choose from. It's working perfect when the cell is not in edit mode but when it's in edit mode when I click the right mouse button it shows windows menu (copy,paste,delete, select all...). So in the datagridview I hadnled the CellEndEdit and there wrote this code:

```
if (MouseButton == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {

            MouseEventArgs e3 = new MouseEventArgs(System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right, 1, Location.X,
                Location.Y, 1);
            DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e2 = new DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs(e.ColumnIndex,
                e.RowIndex, Location.X, Location.Y, e3);
            DataGridValues_CellMouseClick(sender, e2);
        }
```

Where the `MouseButton` is `MouseButtons`. It enteres and do everything but I got the 2 menus(mine and the windows). So I need to disable the windows right click menu. Is there a way to do this? I think the code in `DataGridValues_CellMouseClick(sender, e2);` doesnt matter because it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
  private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Control.ContextMenuStrip = myContextMenuStrip;
    }
```

Comment: its work for me. when right click in editing textbox its show the contextmenustrip which is assigned by me

Comment: I think It should work to but it didn't. I will try again maybe it's because of other events. I will replay you what I have done.

Comment: I tested it on a sample form and it works but for my project it didn't . I still mark your answer as correct and I will continue trying.

Comment: what kind of change's you needed

Comment: I have an event for the datagridview - MouseDown witch detects if a cell is in edit mode and if it is it ends the EditMode. That was the think breaking the program (I have no idea why).